# Is the 'check out of turn' angle illegal?

Tags: rules, angle-shoot

I'm talking about when a player intentionally checks out of turn trying to induce a raise that he then re-raises. Technically the action has changed and his previous action cannot stand, but it feels unethical so I'd be surprised if it isn't addressed in the (say, WSOP) rules somewhere?

Would the player just incur the act-out-of-turn penalty?

Answer (score 3):

It is an angle-shoot in the situation you described, but it's often hard to stop, especially if the player only uses it once or twice a tournament. It's very easy for a player to brush it off as "Sorry didn't realise it wasn't on me" as I think we've all had at least once a moment where we've acted out of turn.

In cases where a player is using this a lot, I've seen it, any dealer should call the floor and they should get a penalty. So to summarise, it's hard to catch especially if a player doesn't abuse it, but it is absolutely a breach of rules as it's an angle shoot.